# Bash Script - Comparing last modified dates

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

Trying to match the `date` output to the same format as `curl` last modified date which is: `Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 08:14:26 GMT`, with the Awk filter as in the script below it is `16 Apr 2020 09:27:51`. The local file's last modified date will be compared with the remote file's last modified date. This script feels flaky and I am considering comparing date strings in a text file as opposed to relying on Http header feedback?

I am aware of the `-z` option in curl, but I want to give the user options via the `if` statements, it can't be fully automated update process, the user (admin) input is needed.

**http header**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 08:43:13 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 08:14:26 GMT
Expires: Thu, 16 Apr 2020 08:44:13 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=60
X-Cache-Status: MISS
X-Backend-ip: x.0.172.195
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: public
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

**script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

local_file="/Users/usr/Desktop/file"
remote_file="www.someurl.com/file"


# current output format: 16 Apr 2020 08:14:26
remote_last_modified_date="$(curl -sI ${remote_file} | grep -E "Last-Modified:" | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$6}' )"

# current output format: Thu Apr 9 18:15:30 SAST 2020  
local_last_modified_date="$(date -r "$local_file" )" 


parsed_remote_last_modified_date="$(date  +%s -d "$remote_last_modified_date")"  
parsed_local_last_modified_date="$(date -r "$local_file")"


  echo "local "$parsed_local_last_modified_date""
   echo "remote "$parsed_remote_last_modified_date""


if [ ${parsed_local_last_modified_date} -lt 
${parsed_remote_last_modified_date} ] ; then


    echo "A new version is available"

else

    echo "latest update already installed"
fi
```

**error:**

```
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing code which you have tried, keep it up. Along with efforts sharing we encourage users to add samples of input and expected output too, so please do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: did you try changing your date format `date '+%a, %d %b %T GMT'` it will return the `Thu, 16 Apr 2020 08:14:26 GMT` Last-Modified you said

Comment: it gives the same error, I don't see syntax errors in the local_last_modified_date variable. tried the date -rf options - did not work either.

Comment: try `local_last_modified_date="$( date  -r "${local_file}" '+%D %T' )`

Comment: Demo :  `$date -r "file.txt" '+%D %T'` --> 
04/16/20 11:36:19

Comment: You are missing `"` at the end in update 2

Comment: I suggest you to get the timestamp corresponding to the last modification date instead of a complex string expressing the date in a sometimes ambiguous way. Further, the test operator `-ot` will fail because its operands must be filenames and not date strings like in your script.

Comment: Note that `grep pattern|awk '{foo}'` is an anti-pattern, since awk should do the grepping: `awk '/pattern/ {foo}'`. You don't need `-E` for a fixed string, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rewritten the script without using the `date` command of the shell, which is not portable across MacOS and GNU Linux. I use `ls` instead, hoping this command is actually portable. Please check:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## variables commented out since we don't have access to theirs values: 
#remote_file="www.someurl.com/file"
#remote_last_modified_date="$(curl -sI ${remote_file} | grep -E "Last-Modified:" | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$6}' )"


## let's suppose we get next result into our variables:
local_file="test"
remote_last_modified_date="16 Apr 2020 08:14:26"

## we don't use the date command, not portable across MacOS and GNU Linux
## we use ls command with the option --time-style instead

## rewrite dates to allow comparison in format +"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S"
local_sortable_date=$(ls -l --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S" "$local_file"| cut -d ' ' -f 6)

remote_year=${remote_last_modified_date:7:4}
remote_month_name=${remote_last_modified_date:3:3}
remote_month=$(echo $remote_month_name | 
  sed 's/Jan/01/;s/Feb/02/;s/Mar/03/;s/Apr/04/;s/May/05/;s/Jun/06/;
    s/Aug/08/;s/Sep/09/;s/Oct/10/;s/Nov/11/;s/Dec/12/')
remote_day=${remote_last_modified_date:0:2}
remote_time=${remote_last_modified_date:12:8}

remote_sortable_date=${remote_year}-${remote_month}-${remote_day}_$remote_time

if [[ $remote_sortable_date > $local_sortable_date ]] ; then
  echo "A new version is available"
  set of commands
else
  echo "latest update already installed"
fi
```

Comment: thank you so much for all your input - it worked. the only thing i had to cgange was "ls" to "gls" after installing gnu core utilities. This works on ubuntu ?

Comment: so mac is able to compare  this format: 2020-04-16_08:14:26 , which I am very pleased about.

Comment: The command `gls` doesn't exist on Linux Ubuntu, but you can define a kind of alias: `[ -x /bin/ls ] && LS=ls || LS=gls` and issue the command `$LS` instead of `ls` or `gls`, according to the presence or not of the executable file `/bin/ls`.

Comment: there is only one thing that I don't get. How do these numbers add up after the variables, i can see what it is doing (extracting), example remote_year=${remote_last_modified_date:7:4} ?

Comment: This is the bash way to select a substring: `${var:7:4}` means the substring of `$var` starting at position `7` (the eighth character since the first postion is `0`) and `4` characters long.

Comment: You had me until *"I use `ls` instead."* Please [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @tripleee: Indeed, this script should be adapted with `stat` and `sort` instead of `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## variables commented out since we don't have access to theirs values: 
#remote_file="www.someurl.com/file"
#remote_last_modified_date="$(curl -sI ${remote_file} | grep -E "Last-Modified:" | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$6}' )"


## let's suppose we get next result into our variables:
local_file="test"
remote_last_modified_date="16 Apr 2020 08:14:26"

## let's compute timestamps
remote_last_modified_timestamp=$(date --date="$remote_last_modified_date" +"%s")
local_last_modified_timestamp=$(date +'%s' -r "${local_file}")

if [ $local_last_modified_timestamp -lt $remote_last_modified_timestamp ] ; then
  echo "A new version is available"
  set of commands
else
  echo "latest update already installed"
fi
```

Comment: thank you Pierre, i still get an illegal time format error. date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
./version_2.sh: line 18: [: : integer expression expected
latest update already installed
wolfs-MacBook:version-check wolf$

Comment: when i use the lt operator on my version, i get local LMD 01 Jan 1970 02:00:00
remote LMD 16 Apr 2020 08:14:26
./version.sh: line 15: [: 01 Jan 1970 02:00:00: integer expression expected
latest update already installed

Comment: line 15: if [ "${local_last_modified_date}" -lt "${remote_last_modified_date}" ] ; then

Comment: ignore the LMD part, that is just a test echo that i put in.

Comment: I fear we don't have the same date function. On which system are you? I supppose MacOS. I am on Linux. The message `usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]` doesn't look like what I get on my system.

Comment: This: `if [ "${local_last_modified_date}" -lt "${remote_last_modified_date}" ]` will not work: you are comparing two strings where the shell is expecting two integers, i.e. two timestamps. I compare `$local_last_modified_timestamp` and `$remote_last_modified_timestamp`. Since these variables only contain integers, I will remove the double quotes from my code.

Comment: thank you @Pierre,  also to no avail. will attempt it on Linux tomorrow, which distro you on? The ultimate goal for all my scripts is to work on both Mac and Linux, which is gonna be difficult with this one. Update 6 is the best result I got to this point.

Comment: You are still trying to compare a date (character strings) and a timestamp (integer). This will not work. You have to compare timestamps with timestamps. Another possibility is to compare date strings as long as they are in a format where the year comes before the (zero padded) month, the month before the (zero padded) day, the day before the hour (zero padded and in the range 00-24), etc...

Comment: If you want your script to work on both Linux and Mac, you will have to avoid the use of the command date.

Comment: By the way, I am on Ubuntu Linux. I deduce that the script you are implementing has to run on all kinds of platforms. This is a good reason to avoid non portable commands as the shell *date* command.

Comment: "The -d flag does not work on OSX unless you download the GNU core utilities"

Comment: local_file_1_stamp="$(date -r "${local_file}" +"%s" )" OUTPUT: 1586448930

Comment: remote_file_stamp="$(date -d "${remote_last_modified_date}" +"%s" )" OUTPUT = date format error